# Calculate Remaining Vacations Days for employees in MVC web application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, model-view-controller

I am developing absent application "C# - MVC5" which will store the state of absence of each employee everyday. The tables are:

1. EmployeesData Table:
   EmpID
   EmpName
   AllowedRegularVacations
   AllowedCasualVacations
2. Transactions Table:
   ID
   EmpID
   EntryDate
   State

I need to get a list with EmpId, EmpName, RemainingRegularVaction, RemainingCasualVaction

I get it with this query:

```
-- Query to calculate remaining regular vactions and remaining casual vacations for each employee

select Employees.Name , (Employees.RegularVacations - ISNULL(Tak1.RequelarVacations,0)) as RemRegularVacations ,
(Employees.CasualVacations - ISNULL(Tak2.RequelarVacations,0)) as RemCasualVacations

from 
Employees left join (select  Employees.Id , count (Transactions.Id) as RequelarVacations
from Employees inner join Transactions on (Employees.Id = Transactions.EmpId)
where (StatusId = 3)
and (Transactions.EntryDate between '01-Jul-19' and '30-Jun-2020')
group by Employees.Id) as Tak1 on (Employees.id = Tak1.Id)

left join (select  Employees.Id , count (Transactions.Id) as RequelarVacations
from Employees inner join Transactions on (Employees.Id = Transactions.EmpId)
where (StatusId = 4)
and (Transactions.EntryDate between '01-Jul-19' and '30-Jun-2020')
group by Employees.Id) as Tak2 on (Employees.id = Tak2.Id)
```

But how to write such a complicated query and retrieve the result in the C# code MVC?

Comment: You can use linq.You just take data of two table in memory collection and filtered out that data.

Comment: I will be very pleased, if you can give me code of pesudo code for your solution

Comment: Since you have the sql already worked out I think the best way would be to use that to populate the data using a tool such as Dapper.  Would that approach be useful to you?

Comment: No, I didn't use Dapper before, I need something as simple as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tries I found the solution and it is worked:

1. Since the year in my company start from 01/07 to 30/06, I write this code to get the start date and the end date which I will use in the query:

   ```
       int month = DateTime.Now.Month;
       int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
       string startDate="";
       string endDate="";

       if (month >= 7 && month <= 12)
       {
            startDate = "01-07-" + year;
            endDate = "30-06-" + (year++);
       }

       else if (month >= 1 && month <= 6)
       {
            startDate = "01-07-" + (year - 1);
            endDate = "30-06-" + year;
       }
   ```
2. Calculate the taken Regular vacation and Casual vacation for each employee from the database:

   ```
           DateTime startDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(startDate);
           DateTime endDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(endDate);
           //calculate Ordinary vacation
           var countOrdinaryVacation = (from trans in db.Transactions
                             where trans.StatusId == 3 &&
                   (trans.EntryDate >= startDateTime && trans.EntryDate <= endDateTime)
                             group trans by trans.EmpId into empg

                             select new

                             {

                                 key = empg.Key,

                                 OrdinaryVaction = empg.Count()

                             }).AsQueryable()  ;
           //calculate Casual Vacation 
           var countCasualVacation = (from trans in db.Transactions
                                        where trans.StatusId == 4 &&
                              (trans.EntryDate >= startDateTime && trans.EntryDate <= endDateTime)
                                        group trans by trans.EmpId into empg

                                        select new

                                        {

                                            key = empg.Key,

                                            CasualVacation = empg.Count()

                                        }).AsQueryable();
   ```
3. get a list from employees table to get the allowed vacations for each employee:

   ```
   var employees = db.Employees.ToList();
   ```
4. Create new view model class to contain the fields we will use in the view:

   ```
   public class EmpVacations
   {
   public int EmpId { get; set; }
   public string EmpName { get; set; }
   public int? AllowedRegularVacation { get; set; }
   public int? AllowedCasualVacation { get; set; }
   public int? TakenRegularVacation { get; set; }
   public int? TakenCasualVacation { get; set; }

   public int? RemRegularVacation { get; set; }
   public int? RemCasualVacation { get; set; }
   ```

   }
5. make a list of type EmpVacations  in the controller which will contain all data I needed for employees:

   ```
   List<EmpVacations> empVacations = new List<EmpVacations>();
   foreach (var emp in employees)
           {
               EmpVacations emp1 = new EmpVacations();
               emp1.EmpId = emp.Id;
               emp1.EmpName = emp.Name;
               emp1.AllowedRegularVacation = emp.RegularVacations;
               emp1.AllowedCasualVacation = emp.CasualVacations;
               emp1.TakenRegularVacation = countOrdinaryVacation.Where(x => x.key == emp1.EmpId).FirstOrDefault() == null ? 0 : countOrdinaryVacation.Where(x => x.key == emp1.EmpId).FirstOrDefault().OrdinaryVaction;
               emp1.TakenCasualVacation = countCasualVacation.Where(x => x.key == emp1.EmpId).FirstOrDefault() ==null ? 0 : countCasualVacation.Where(x => x.key == emp1.EmpId).FirstOrDefault().CasualVacation;
           emp1.RemRegularVacation = emp1.AllowedRegularVacation - emp1.TakenRegularVacation;
           emp1.RemCasualVacation = emp1.AllowedCasualVacation - emp1.TakenCasualVacation;
           empVacations.Add(emp1);

               }
   ```

   6. send the list in a view bag to the view

      ```
        ViewBag.EmpData = empVacations;
      ```